# What is the difference between @Bean with @Order specified and @FilterRegistrationBean with set order?

Tags: spring-boot

I have descendant of `org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`(mostly copy-pasted `org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter`), which logs incoming requests and related responses. Defined as:

```
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Bean
    public MyLoggingFilter logFilter() {
//...
    }
```

but if authentication fails, it does not log anything, even though I have highest order precedence. This code instead:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyLoggingFilter> logFilter() {
    MyLoggingFilter myFilter = ...;


    FilterRegistrationBean<MyLoggingFilter> regBean= new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    regBean.setFilter(myFilter);
    regBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    regBean.setOrder(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER - 1);

    return regBean;
}
```

*does* work. I don't understand the difference, can someone explain? It seems to me, that `@Order` over `@Bean` only specifies order say for `@ControllerAdvice`s, `@EventListener`s, etc, but *not* for filters, and these I can set only via `FilterRegistrationBean`, but this is weird conclusion...